# CSS - not-allowed is not a cursor value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When opening `bootstrap.min.css` in Aptana IDE editing window, there is an error message about the `bootstrap.min.css` file. The error is:

```
Value Error: cursor(http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/ui.html#propdef-cursor)not-allowed is not a cursor value
```

However on w3school.org, `not-allowed` is listed a value for cursor:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=not-allowed

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Where do you get that error message?

Comment: Note that although W3Schools is not W3C, the W3C itself also lists `not-allowed` as a cursor type. http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150519/#cursor

Comment: I'm confused. You say "on w3.org, not-allowed is listed" but the URL that follows is W3Schools. Did you paste the wrong link by chance? Was what @Mr Lister posted above the one you meant to link to?

Comment: `@BoltClock`, it should be w3school.org. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: `@Michal Szyndel`, the error shows in Apatana IDE. a red x appears when opening bootstrap.min.css in editing window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is probably based on CSS2.

In the CSS2 spec there isn't a not-allowed value. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/ui.html#propdef-cursor

In CSS3 there is a not-allowed value defined. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor

Still the question is, where do you get that errormessage?

Comment: The error message reads word-for-word identically to a typical Value Error message emitted by the Jigsaw W3C CSS validator. However, its CSS2 option links to the 2008 revision - the one given in the OP links to the 1998 revision. Although both revisions are obsolete (the current is 2011's CSS2.1 which is currently being superseded by a CSS2.2), this discrepancy intrigues me nonetheless.

Comment: `@Hans`, the error shows in editing window of Aptana IDE. Is it possible because Apatana is only compliant with CSS2?

Comment: @user938363 I have tested the code .not{cursor:not-allowed}  in https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ With the option CSS 2.1 you get your error. With the option CSS 3 it validates. So yes, I think you get this error because Apatane seems to support only CSS 2.x